# resizing images for slideshow

Tags: javascript, css, image, slideshow

I'm trying to resize my images for a slideshow. When I plug them into an array and code them into a slideshow, the cropping is kind of off. I tried using object-position in CSS but that changes all the images in one shot and what works for one image doensn't necessarily work for others.

Here is the HTML:

```
 <container class="main-img-cont">
   <img class="main-img" alt="">
 </container>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
    .main-img-cont {
    width: 100%;
    height: 650px;
    display: flex;


    img {
        width: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
        object-position: 0 30%;
    } // closes img
} // closes .main-img
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload = () => {
    var mainImg = document.querySelector('.main-img');
    let slideshow = [
        '../img/jevon_cochran_pelourinho.jpg',
        '../img/me_in_Pernambues.JPG',
        '../img/quibdo_boat_ride.jpg'
    ];
    var index = 0;
    var interval = 1000;
    function slide() {
        mainImg.src = slideshow[index];
        index++;
        if (index >= slideshow.length) {
            index = 0;
        }
    }

    setInterval(slide, interval);
}
```

Comment: Please add screenshots of current and expected behaviour.

Comment: Please update your code with placeholder images that we can actually view. Use a service like placeholder.com and add images that have the same dimensions as the images you are using.

Comment: You can just view the actual page: Documents/My Site/html/bd_index.html @disinfor

Comment: How could we possibly view a page on your computer?

Comment: Oops, I didn't catch that mistake. Here is the correct link: https://jevoncochran.github.io/Documents/My%20Site/html/bd_index.html @disinfor

Comment: Offsite links should not be used - once you fix the problem, the link becomes useless to future visitors. You need to update your question. Use the `snippet` feature and update your code to include placeholder images.